# vuex store is unable to trigger in routed components

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

My vuex store is all set up and everything works just fine, however, I can only commit my mutations only in components that are directly imported in src App.vue.

For example, the `resetState` in Header.vue triggers as should when I click the button cause it is imported directly in src/App.vue

```
<template>
      <v-btn
        icon
        to="/"
        id="no-background-hover"
        @click="resetState"
      >
          ///
      </v-btn>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue'
import { MutationTypes } from '@/store/mutation-types'

export default Vue.extend({
  name: 'Header',

  methods: {
    resetState () {
      this.$store.commit(MutationTypes.RESET_STATE, 0)
    }
  },

})
</script>
```

But when I have this exact component in any of my views/BlahBlahBlah.vue that is routed, nothing happens when I click the button

Here's the main.ts

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueTypedJs from 'vue-typed-js'

import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import './assets/sass/index.sass'
import store from './store'
import vuetify from './plugins/vuetify'

Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.use(VueTypedJs)
new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  vuetify,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

Comment: Did you look at Vue dev tools? Any errors/warnings in console?

Comment: @Anatoly I did. No errors, nothing

Comment: Can you share your `main.js`?

Comment: @Prime  I just did

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the fix, all I needed to do was wrap `router-view` in `keep-alive` tag

```
<keep-alive>
        <router-view/>
</keep-alive>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem arises because "to="/"" is executed before referring to the store, and because it refreshes the page the command is not sent.

Here's how you should do it:

```js
<template>
      <v-btn
        icon
        id="no-background-hover"
        @click="resetState"
      >
          ///
      </v-btn>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue'
import { MutationTypes } from '@/store/mutation-types'

export default Vue.extend({
  name: 'Header',

  methods: {
    resetState () {
      this.$store.commit(MutationTypes.RESET_STATE, 0)
      window.location.href = '/'
    }
  },

})
</script>
```